# asp.net Core 3.1 Filter Form trigger refresh of page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am struggling to figure out the proper way of achieving this objective.

I have a view that contains a bunch of data. At the top of the view, I have added a form with some options to filter on. Once they click submit, I want to trigger a call to the C# controller to filter out the data and trigger the page to refresh. I was able to do this without passing any parameters by calling on the window to refresh via javascript. But as soon as I tried to get the user entered data, I keep hitting a wall. When trying to pass to javascript, it always loaded the initial state of the model. So I tried changing it to use a form that calls the action, which worked on the backend but now it just errors out 500 when it returns the view and I have no idea why.

What is the proper way of doing something like this?

Summary.cshtml

```
@model SummaryModel

<!-- ... excluding content -->
<form id="form" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="refreshSummary">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EpicType" class="label-control"></label>
            <select asp-for="EpicType" class="form-control" asp-items="@QueryModel.EpicTypes"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="EpicType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group" style="align-content: center; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5px;" ;>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0">Apply</button>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- ... excluding content -->
```

Rest of the page is just displaying data, not sure its relevant to question. On apply, I want to update the page with the newly filtered results.

HomeController.cs

```
/// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the list of epics based on filters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FilterModel">filterData</param>
    /// <returns>result</returns>
    public IActionResult refreshSummary(SummaryModel filterData)
    {
        .. do filtering here ..

        filteredPorts.Sort();
        return View("Summary");
    }
```

I hit this call fine. But the return is when a 500 error hits and I get no insight in visual studio as to why. 
In startup I have:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Summary}");
```

Comment: your summary view is expecting a model of type SummaryModel but you are not passing any model to view.

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is not provided completely. We cannot know exactly what you
>   did in refreshSummary action.

But the 500 error here is that you did not `re-bind` the corresponding data source to the `select (@QueryModel.EpicTypes)` when you returned to the Summary view.

When returning to the Summary view, you need to return the value of `@QueryModel.EpicTypes` as a parameter and rebind the selected data source.

```
    public IActionResult refreshSummary(SummaryModel filterData)
    { 
        //  .. do filtering here ..
        filteredPorts.Sort();
        return View("Index", summary);//here summary contains @QueryModel.EpicTypes data
    }
```

Comment: The EpicTypes is a static list. That doesn't seem to have anything to do with this. I can hard code the list and still have the issue

Comment: @JeremyK, could you show us more detailed code about your issue?